# Silverlight Control Lifecycle

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Could anyone tell me the events that are fired during a Silverlight control's lifecycle please?

For instance in ASP.NET you would have PreInit, Init, PreLoad, Load, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much Googling I came across the following. It's not brilliant, and it appplies to Silverlight 2, but it's a start...

http://www.dotblogs.com.tw/kan/archive/2009/03/03/7351.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[This is a much better control lifecycle description](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/10/11/control-lifecycle.aspx).